# Mapping income to binary

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to map the `Income` column of a dataframe to 0 or 1. A new column called `Income Binary` is created. It is based on the `Income` column. A value of 1 means that it is true for the condition that the person's income is more than >50K. Otherwise a value of 0 means the condition is false, meaning that the person's income is less than or equal to <=50K. If the record for the `Income` is >50K the value would be 1 for Income Binary. Otherwise it would be 0. The code compiles, but there is an execution error.  The code is posted below. Then when I check the number of values for Income Binary it has all 0's, which means it is all false, which I know is not the case.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your income column is a string as pointed out by Trenton_M. It is probably something along this line `df['IncomeBinary'] = [1 if x == '>50K' else 0 for x in df['Income']]`

Answer (score 0):

### Use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

- The code to determine `Income_Binary` isn't shown, but I suspect you're not properly evaluating the `str` in the `Income` column.

  - `print(type(df.Income.loc[0])) >>> str` is probably the case for your data

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'income': [random.choice(['<=50K', '>50K']) for _ in range(1000)]})

# map values as desired
df['inc_bin'] = df.income.map({'<=50K': 0, '>50K': 1})

# Output:

income  inc_bin
  >50K        1
  >50K        1
 <=50K        0
 <=50K        0
 <=50K        0
```